# Firefox with multiple profiles without -no-remote in widnows

Tags: firefox, profile

I need to open Firefox with multiple profiles without -no-remote in windows

I can use -no-remote to open multiple profiles like

```
firefox -P production -no-remote
firefox -P test -no-remote
```

but issue is I have outside app that need to open a new url like

```
firefox -P production -url ...
firefox -P test -url ...
```

the issue is that the remote command function is disabled when instance is lauched with -no-remote

seems also that -new-instance doesn't work in windows.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to keep the -no-remote and execute remote command using [Remote Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remote-control/) addon